# how to hide div class while textbox filled

Tags: javascript

How to hide `div` class using JavaScript while textbox is filled?

I want to hide class **loadData** while **textbox(t1)** is filled.

**Example code:**

```
<input type="text" name="t1" placeholder="search">


<div class="loadData">
     // some content here....
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `while textbox(t1) filled`

Comment: sorry i forget to add input type value. Now see that code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **jQuery**. Check the value of text field on `keyup` event and perform operation accordingly.

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function() {
    ($.trim($(this).val()) != '') ? $('.loadData').hide() : $('.loadData').show();
})
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/d16exy4c/)

Comment: `$(':text').on('keyup', function() {
    $('.loadData').toggle($.trim($(this).val()));
});
`

Comment: You can add this in your answer as `Update/Edit`

Comment: @Tushar But it will not work with this properly as `toggle` don't take arguments like that. https://jsfiddle.net/vd5azw1g/

Answer (score 4):

```
    window.onload = function () {
    elements = document.getElementsByName("t1"); 
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("loadData");
    elements.onblur = function() { divs.style.visibility="hidden"; };
    };
```

Comment: Will `blur` event occurs on `div`, I think it occurs only on `input` elements

Comment: How it will decide if the `textbox` is filled or not?

Comment: @tinka `I want to hide class loadData while textbox(t1) is filled.`. Where you've checked the status of `textbox`?

Answer (score 1):

User `jQuery's` blur function.

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $("[name=t1]").blur(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $(".loadData").hide();
    }
  });
})
</script>
```

**Explanation:**

You are calling a function on `blur` event of textbox.

It means user has filled the textbox and want to leave textbox.

In this function body, hide the div with class `loadData`.

Comment: How it will decide if the textbox is filled or not?

Comment: Thanks @b0s3. :) This is the way we learn from this community. cheers :)

Answer (score -1):

add `onblur="showdiv()"` to input box and add this function in your javascript

```
function showdiv()    
{    
    var a=document.getElementsByClassName('loadData');
    a[0].style.visibility='hidden';    
}
```